# no me manda un FILE en php

Tags: php, javascript

estoy tratando de realizar un insert con adjuntos pero no me los esta mandando en form

aqui el error

string(164) "INSERT INTO ordenes (asunto, detail,quien_solicita, fecha_resolucion, estatus, adjunto) VALUES ('dfgdfg','asdgd','Rmendoza1', '2021-03-30T20:43', 'Pendiente','')"

aqui tengo elcodigo

```
$adjunto = (isset($_FILES['adjunto'])) ? $_FILES['adjunto'] : null;
$ruta_destino_archivo = "archivos/{$adjunto['name']}";
$archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($adjunto['tmp_name'], $ruta_destino_archivo);

$asunto=!empty($_POST['asunto']) ? $_POST['asunto'] : NULL;
$detail=!empty($_POST['detail']) ? $_POST['detail'] : NULL;
$fecha_resolucion=!empty($_POST['fecha_resolucion']) ? $_POST['fecha_resolucion'] : NULL;
$estatus=!empty($_POST['estatus']) ? $_POST['estatus'] : NULL;


$sql="INSERT INTO ordenes (asunto, detail,quien_solicita, fecha_resolucion, estatus, adjunto) 
VALUES  ('$asunto','$detail','".$_SESSION['usuario']."', '$fecha_resolucion', '$estatus','".$adjunto["name"]."')";

$data = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if($data)
{
  //echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    //alert("Guardado Exitosamente!");
    //window.location.href="supervisor.php";
    //</script>';
}else{
  echo 'error';
  var_dump($sql);
}
var_dump($archivo_ok);
```

este es una parte del form

```
<center><strong>
Recuerda adjuntar tú evidencia.</strong>
<input type="file" name="adjunto"  id="adjunto"/></center><br>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<strong>Status:</strong>
```

aqui muestro la carpeta que tengo compartida en linux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Declaraste el `form` como `multipart`? Conviene que pongas el HTML del formulario completo para revisarlo. Y que depures con un `var_dump($_FILES);` en PHP para ver si está llegando algo y de qué forma. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" agrege este y ya me agarro la duda es porque en otro form que tengo no lo necesita ya que solo tengo action POST en ese form pero aqui si lo necesite

Comment: Debes declarar como `multipart` todos los formularios que envían archivos adjuntos. Eso es lo que significa `multipart` precisamente, que en el form viajan dos tipos de datos, los normales, que se obtienen con `$_POST` o con `$_GET` según el método y los archivos que se obtienen con `$_FILES`. Te lo explico con detalle en una respuesta.

Comment: a ok vale vale graciasd

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR;

Los elementos `form` con método `post` pueden tener tres valores para la propiedad `enctype`, que son: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` es el valor por defecto y envía los datos en una cadena; `multipart/form-data` para enviar archivos adjuntos, en cuyo caso se envían los datos en dos partes; `text/plain` añadido a partir de HTML5, sirve para enviar texto plano.

Significa entonces que en todos aquellos formularios en los que vayas a enviar archivos adjuntos, debes declarar un `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Eso indica que al momento de enviar el formulario los datos se van a serializar en **dos partes** (multipart). Por un lado los datos habituales como inputs de tipo `text` y otros, que se recuperarán en el servidor con `$_POST` y por otra parte los archivos que irían en inputs de tipo `file` y que se recuperarán en el servidor con `$_FILES`.

---

Esto viene explicado con detalle en la [especificación HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-enctype):

#### `enctype`

Cuando el valor del atributo `method` es `post`, este atributo es el  [tipo MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type) del contenido que es usado para enviar el formulario al servidor.

Los posibles valores son:

- **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**: El valor por defecto si un atributo no está especificado.
- **`multipart/form-data`**: Usar este valor si se está usando el elemento `<input>` con el atributo type ajustado a "`file`".
- **`text/plain`** (HTML5)